# Break up a file to attach to an email

Tags: file-transfer, attachments

I have a file (a .chm file) that I need to email.  It is 200 MB in size.  My email client will not allow attachments that big.

I need a tool that will break it up into 50 MB files and then put it back together on the other side.

I tried 7-zip but it can only do 1.4 MB and 650 MB.  (also the file will not compress via 7-zip's ultimate compression algorithms.)

Any other ideas?

Comment: Just remember, a lot of e-mail server won't support anything over 10MB, you may need to go smaller than 50

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use 7-zip, it may look a bit confusing but this drop down box can actually be edited with a custom value as well:

(Depending on the email application's implementation, 50 [megabytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte) could be 50000000 bytes, 51200000 bytes or even 52428800 bytes. I'd use 50000000 to be safe as it's the lowest possibility.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Look at 7zip again. If using the GUI that "split to volumes, bytes:" field is a combo-box. Yes, you can select the canned options of 1.44 and 650, but you can also just type in your own value as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide another answer, (the one's above are correct and good) WinRAR will also do it.  You can get it from [http://www.rarlab.com](http://www.rarlab.com/)